# Не удается отфильтровать массив объектов

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть вот такой объект:

```
data: Object
    attachments: Object
        animations: Array[0]
        audios:  Array[4]
            0: Object
                artist: "Perturbator"
                duration: 262
                title: "Humans Are Such Easy Prey"
            1: Object
                artist: "Johann Sebastian Bach"
                duration: 505
                title: "Toccata and Fugue in D minor, BWV 565"
            2: Object
                artist: "Sabaton - Primo Victoria"
                duration: 272
                title: "Primo Victoria"
            3: Object
                artist: "Johny Cash"
                duration: 218
                title: "Hurt..    I hurt myself today"
```

Я пытаюсь сделать возможность фильтрации. Скажем, если в одном из свойств присутствует слово "Victoria", то весь объект `data` попадает в результаты фильтрации, если нет - не попадает.

Пытаюсь фильтровать вот так:

```
console.log($filter('filter')(content, {
    attachments: self.textSearch
}));
```

Вот так:

```
console.log($filter('filter')(content, {
    attachments: {
        audios: self.textSearch
    } 
}));
```

И вот так:

```
console.log($filter('filter')(content, {
    attachments: {
        audios: {
            artist: self.textSearch,
            title: self.textSearch
        }
    } 
}));
```

Но всегда получаю пустой результат. Как правильно реализовать фильтрацию в этом случае?

Comment: приведи пример объекта в виде json. И что за _content_? ну и так как ты хочешь не получится, потому что нужно указать полный путь до проверяемого свойства, а у тебя оно во внутреннем массиве - пиши свою функцию компаратор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По совету @Grundy написал свою функцию-компаратор:

```
content = $filter('filter')(content, function(post) {
    var text = post.text.toLowerCase();
    var search = self.textSearch.toLowerCase();
    if (text.indexOf(search) != -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < post.attachments.audios.length; i++) {
            var track = post.attachments.audios[i];
            var text = (track.artist + track.title).toLowerCase();
            if (text.indexOf(search) != -1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

П.С. Кстати, если вы видите какие-то узкие места, которые можно ускорить, оставьте комментарий.